# .NET Multithreaded Access to Shared Login Session

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, locking

I'm working on a Web API application which connects to a backend system via an API. One challenge of working with the API is that it requires a remote session to be maintained that is shared between all threads/requests to the Web API. The session expires every few hours and needs to be "refreshed" via a login.

A simplified version of my current implementation is below:

```
private static Object loginLock = new Object();

if(!Api.IsLoggedIn) 
{
    lock(loginLock)
    {
        if(!Api.IsLoggedIn)
        {
            Api.Login();
        }
    }
}

// Do stuff with the API
```

Under high concurrent load, when a login is required, threads get stacked up at the lock and are let through one at a time upon a successful login which is causing a performance bottleneck.

What I'm looking for is a way to block all threads when a login is required, but let them all through upon successful login.

Is there a better pattern for addressing this issue? Googling seems to indicate that `ReaderWriterLockSlim` or `Monitor Wait/Pulse/PulseAll` might be better candidates than a standard lock.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens when the session expires after the `Api.IsLoggedIn` check but before actual use of the Api occurs?

Comment: The API call would fail with an "no valid session" error, but we haven't seen that case (so far).

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Requests queuing up seems unavoidable. But once the session becomes available the queue should clear extremely quickly. Like one million thread per second or so.

Comment: That is a good question. I get what your saying but that doesn't appear to be what we're seeing. Let me see if I can get some more profiling around this. Maybe I'm trying to solve the wrong problem.

Comment: Are you really sure that this is a problem? `lock` is *very* fast.

Comment: `lock` always wins in performance counters, as all other variants add some overhead on CPU to the threads being spin without action. `ReaderWriterLockSlim` will not so fast as `Monitor` class usage.

Answer (score 2):

It's an unusual problem, and I'm not aware of anything built in that specifically addresses this.

Bearing in mind that I've knocked this up in a few minutes, and so I'd definitely advise not using this until plenty of people have had a chance to look at it and point out its flaws, this is what I thought of:

```
private Task _loginLock = null;

public void DoLoggedInCheck()
{
    if (!Api.IsLoggedIn)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();
        var tsk = tcs.Task;
        var result = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _loginLock, tsk, null);
        if (result == null)
        {
            if (!Api.IsLoggedIn)
            {
                Api.Login();
            }
            Interlocked.Exchange(ref _loginLock, null);
            tcs.SetResult(1);
        }
        else
        {
            result.Wait();
        }
    }
}
```

The logic being that, out of all of the threads that spot that a login is required, they all compete (via the `CompareExchange`) to be the one to volunteer to fix the problem. One of them wins and does the task, the remainder just wait for the winner to signal their success.

There's still a small amount of raciness here, but it should be rare.

Comment: `if (result == tsk)` this will never true, as `CompareExchange` returns original value of the field, and it is some other task or `null` incase of first thread. And if some thread will `Exchange` `_loginLock` with `null`, all others in this case will got `null` with `CompareExchange`, so `result.Wait();` will crash.

Comment: "There's still a small amount of raciness here" that is interesting way of putting things. Raciness is binary thing, it is either there or not.

Comment: I would use a Lazy<T> for this instead of tasks.

Comment: @usr - the point here is that, each time the API needs to be logged in, a new set of threads need to coordinate their activity. I'm not sure how a `Lazy` would help here.

Comment: You could create a new lazy for each epoch.

Comment: @Andrey - The races I'm thinking about are things like "if thread T1 gets to this point, then thread T2 runs, then thread T1 resumes hours later...". Given the existence of races within usage of the API, I'm just saying that the races are there.

Comment: @usr - who creates the lazy? How do you ensure that everyone agrees on that?

Comment: Just like you create the task. You could even use LazyInitializer to create the lazy.

Comment: @usr - that has the wrong semantics in my head then. In my version, everyone bids to perform a task. Someone wins. And then everyone else waits for that task to be completed. Your version may have some wins I'm not aware of, but I'm aiming for simplicity.

Comment: It would work the same way. Everyone bids to create a lazy, n-1 lazies are dropped and then everyone consumes the single lazy that came through. It's the same that your code does but uses more built-in features.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to resolve it only using worker threads I don't see any other ways, there is a critical section and this is nature of critical section that only 1 thread can pass it at a time. Completely other approach would be do delegate handling of critical section to separate thread. I am not sure that it will be more performant (most probably it will be much slower) but once Api is logged in there will be no traffic jam.

```
        private static AutoResetEvent requestLogin = new AutoResetEvent();
        private static ManualResetEvent responseLogin = new ManualResetEvent();

        //Worker thread:

        if(!Api.IsLoggedIn) 
        {
            requestLogin.Set();
            responseLogin.WaitOne();
        }

        //Login thread

        requestLogin.WaitOne();
        if(!Api.IsLoggedIn)
        {
            Api.Login();
        }
        responseLogin.Set();
```